# LINQ Syntax for Current Revision

Tags: c#, linq, exception, group-by, oracle11g

How can I write this SQL statement using C# and LINQ? I am quering an Oracle database and the table has multiple revisions of the records. Therefore, I want onyl the current revision of each record contained in the table.

The SQL looks like this:

```
select TP_ID, TP_TEXT, TP_DEFN_SAKEY
from TP_DEFN tp1
where tp1.TP_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' and
      tp1.FAMILY_ID = 1 and 
      tp1.TP_DEFN_REV_DTS = (select max(TP_DEFN_REV_DTS) 
from TP_DEFN tp2 
where tp2.family_id = tp1.family_id and tp2.tp_id = tp1.tp_id ) 
order by TP_ID
```

`TP_DEFN_REV_DTS` is the date time field that stores the current revision.

I am a beginner with LINQ and have been struggling to find an workable solution. Every time that I try grouping in the LINQ query I get an error

> GroupBy is not supported

Comment: Could you add a code sample of what you tried earlier?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework with the Oracle Provider?

Comment: Actually, `GroupBy` might be just that; not supported by your Linq provider. I've at least experienced this with the NHibernate provider.

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys, We are using EF, to interact with our Oracle database. We are also using ODP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, and not knowing which LINQ provider you're using...

```
var q = from tp1 in Context.TP_DEFN
        where tp1.TP_ACTIVE_FLAG == "Y"
            && tp1.FAMILY_ID == 1
            && tp1.TP_DEFN_REV_DTS 
               == Context.TP_DEFN.Where(tp2 => tp2.FAMILY_ID == tp1.FAMILY_ID
                                            && tp2.TP_ID == tp1.TP_ID)
                                 .Max(tp2 => tp2.TP_DEFN_REV_DTS)
        orderby tp1.TP_ID
        select new
        {
            tp1.TP_ID,
            tp1.TP_TEXT,
            tp1.TP_DEFN_SAKEY
        };
```

Comment: Wow, thank you Craig! Since I posted this we have learned a great deal about the syntax of LINQ and the use of tools such as LINQPad.

Comment: Now that I have tried your suggestion on multiple tables in our DB I really would like to thankn you again, we have many tables where we track revisions and learning this syntax was critical.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var res = 
                from tp1 in TP_DEFN
                where tp1.TP_ACTIVE_FLAG == "Y" &&
                tp1.FAMILY_ID == 1 &&
                tp1.TP_DEFN_REV_DTS == (from tp2 in TP_DEFN
                                        where tp2.FAMILY_ID == tp1.FAMILY_ID &&
                                        tp2.TP_ID == tp1.TP_ID
                                        select tp2.TP_DEFN_REV_DTS).Max()
                orderby tp1.TP_ID
                select new 
                {
                    tp1.TP_ID,
                    tp1.TP_TEXT,
                    tp1.TP_DEFN_SAKEY
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using entity framework or linq-to-sql, you can just pass the direct sql if you want (although that'll prevent change tracking, at least by default).

For EF, use ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx

For L2S, use DataContext.ExecuteQuery: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx